# Некорректное отображение страницы

Tags: веб-программирование, html, css

Сверстал страничку. Сверстал у ноутбука, у пк все криво.
Причём все ровно только у меня на ноуте.

Несколько дней мучил html, css, js, но сделать страницу адаптивной не вышло.
Фреймворки применять не собираюсь.

Почему все кривится? Хотя должно всё быть нормально. Везде нормально, но главная скоро меня доконает.

Как вы поймёте из того, что там наделано, верстать у меня не очень выходит.

Страничка: http://helpost.ru/index1.php

Пример, как на ноуте:

[image]

Comment: @Айнур Шакиров, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете float не забывайте отмену обтекания
http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/plavayushchie-elementy также вместо float попробуйте использовать display: inline-block

http://habrahabr.ru/post/161581/

Answer (score 0):

Не мешало бы избавится от

```
margin: 14px 21px 47px 0px;
margin-top: -420px;    
margin-top: -300px;
```

такого рода...